# How to read files in python(colab) with many layers?

Tags: python

My dataset is Nucleus dataset(on kaggle).

I split them into two files, one is train,the other is test.

I think my problem is that I can't read data correctly.

For example,
`('/content/drive/My Drive/Nucleus dataset/train/fc9269fb2e651cd4a32b65ae164f79b0a2ea823e0a83508c85d7985a6bed43cf', ['masks', 'images'], []).`

There is only one photo in images folder.

But there are many photos in masks folder.

So, how can I correct my code to let the above runs?

```
import json, time, torch
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive/')

from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import numpy as np

import cv2
from PIL import Image


from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join


class Nucleus dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, split="train", pytorch=True):
        super().__init__()

        self.root = '/content/drive/My Drive/Nucleus dataset/'

        self.split = split

        if self.split == 'train':
          print("get dataset: train")
          self.root = self.root + 'train'

        elif self.split == 'test':
          print("get dataset: test")
          self.root = self.root + 'test'
        
        else:
          print("split parameter is not setted")

        self.filelist = [f for f in listdir(self.root) if isfile(join(self.root, f))]
        print("folder_location: " + self.root)
        print("first_filename_under_folder: " + self.filelist[0])
        print("files_num_under_folder: " + str(len(self.filelist)))


    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.filelist)

    def prepare_image_cv2(self, img): 
        img -= np.array((104.00698793,116.66876762,122.67891434)) 
        img = np.transpose(img, (2, 0, 1)) # (H x W x C) to (C x H x W)
        return img

    def prepare_label_PIL(self, lb):  
        lb = np.expand_dims(lb, axis=2) 
        lb = np.transpose(lb, (2, 0, 1)) 
        return lb

    def __getitem__(self, index): 
        
        img_filename = self.filelist[index]
        filename = img_filename.split(".")[0]
        label_filename = filename+"_mask.gif"

        
        img = cv2.imread(join(self.root, img_filename))
        #print("before - img size:"+str(img.shape))
        img = cv2.resize(img, (480, 320), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR) 
        #print("after - img size:"+str(img.shape))

        
        label = Image.open(join(self.root+"_mask", label_filename))
        #print("before - label size:"+str(label.size))
        label = label.resize((480, 320),Image.BILINEAR)
        #print("after - label size:"+str(label.size))
        

       
        img_np = np.array(img, dtype=np.float32)
        label_np = np.array(label, dtype=np.float32)
        
        
        img_np = self.prepare_image_cv2(img_np)
        label_np = self.prepare_label_PIL(label_np)
        #print("img:"+str(img.shape))
        #print("label:"+str(label.size))
        #print("img_np:"+str(img_np.shape))
        #print("label_np:"+str(label_np.shape))

        return img_np, label_np, filename
`
```